# Why is my register link not working?

Tags: html, hyperlink, href, atag

For some reason my register link won't work within my header, any help would be appreciated.

code (in header):

```
<header>
    <img src="PSE.jpg" height="100" width="250" alt="Logo" /> 
    <div id="search"><input type="text" name="query" class="query" id="query" value="Search..." autocomplete="off">
    <input class="button" type="submit" name="submit" value="Go"></div>
    <div id="login">Login</div>
    <div id="register"><a href="register.html">Register</a></div>       
    <form id="user"><input type="text" name="Username" value="Username"/>
    <input type="password" name="Password" value="password"/></form>        
    <div id="facebook"><a><img src="facebook-icon.png" height="25" width="25" alt="facebook"/></a></div>
    <div id="twitter"><a><img src="twitter-icon.jpg" height="25" width="25" alt="twitter"/></a></div>
    <div id="youtube"><a><img src="youtube-icon.png" height="25" width="25" alt="youtube"/></a></div>
</header>
```

css:

```
header{
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 100%;
    height: 110px;
    text-align: left;
    display: block;
    background-color:#268ACC;
    }

    header img{
    text-align:left;
    padding-left: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
    padding-top: 5px;
    }       
    #search {
    text-align: left;
    position: relative;
    left: 300px;
    bottom: 40px;
    }
    #user{
    text-align: left;
    position: relative;
    left: 550px;
    bottom: 60px;
    }
    #login{
    text-align: left;
    position: relative;
    bottom: 40px;
    left: 550px;
    margin-top:-50px;
    }
    #register{
    text-align: left;
    position: relative;
    bottom: 65px;
    left: 710px;        
    }
    #register a{
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0px;
    text-decoration: none;
    vertical-align: middle; 
    }   
    #facebook{
    text-align: right;
    position: relative;
    bottom: 160px;
    padding-right: 5px;
    }
    #twitter{
    text-align: right;
    position: relative;
    bottom: 160px;
    padding-right: 5px;
    }
    #youtube{
    text-align: right;
    position: relative;
    bottom: 160px;
    padding-right: 5px;
```

edit: now added all header elements and css. 
Just to add some detail because it wants me to, the layout of the header in an image on the left hand side followed by a search bar then login inputs, social media image and the register link which i am trying to fix.

Comment: The HTML is fine. Make sure your filepath to register.html is correct.

Comment: register.html is in the source folder with all my other pages, so i don't know whats wrong...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Becuase of the relative positioning, the div is being overlapped. So just add a z-index with a high number like `9999` to your relative positioned div like this:

```
#register{
    text-align: left;
    position: relative;
    bottom: -20px;
    left: 100px;
    z-index: 9999;        
}
```

And it should work beautifully.

Comment: thanks. only problem then is that i do need it in that position as that where it fits in with my header.

Comment: Can you provide a bit more codes of your page structure

Comment: Added some more detail for you.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to set the width and height of div.

Try this:

```
#register{
  text-align: left;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 80px;
}
#register a{
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0px;
  text-decoration: none;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```